# Unable to upload file on AWS [Ubuntu] using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have AWS instance with Ubuntu and PHP configured. Every things work perfect. Only file upload not working. Application developed in PHP [codeigniter]

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$config = [
            'upload_path'    =>  "./data/user-avatar",
            'allowed_types'  =>  'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|JPEG',
            'encrypt_name'   =>   TRUE
         ];

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

 if($this->upload->do_upload())
 {
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    echo $image = $data['file_name'];
 } else {
   echo "I am here in else";
 }
```

It executive else block directly. Application work fine on local.

1. Checked upload dir permission its 777
2. Check on phpinfo file upload is on

Any help to find of the error will be appreciated.

Thanks 
Prashant

Comment: You can check your error in file upload using this ` $error = $this->upload->display_errors();` you can try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure your **max upload size** and **max post** are big enough on `php.ini` or your main php config file?
it could not accept files bigger than X;

Also you could get the `$data['error']` to see if you get any code > 0 and find a answer from this; maybe `$error = $this->upload->display_errors();` could tell you more

Also check if your directory exists, using `is_dir()` to make sure you are not pointing to a different relative path (worth the check).

Comment: Thank it helps. I thought ` $this->upload->display_errors();` this works after upload one.